# Why can’t I change the styles of my HTML element using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem, and I made this test code to show you my problem.

- HTML code: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qlZx.png
- Javascript code: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYvuq.png

What I want to do is to change the styles of the id. But for some reason it doesn't work.

I don't know what’s happening and I really need your help. Thanks.

Comment: You should post the whole thing. No one will help you with that. And IMHO this is stackoverflow question.

Comment: 1-you don't know if someone could help me... and 2-i tought this was the right place cuz' the title says "webmaster" not "make web design questions on stackoverflow". ;)

Comment: read the faq: "Please note that if your question is about detailed HTML, JavaScript, or CSS coding, it might be a better fit on Stack Overflow. We prefer questions here about problems or issues that affect entire websites."

Comment: You made a *picture* of your test code to show us. Could you post a working (or rather not working) example on http://jsfiddle.net/ instead please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your original code you are incorrectly referring to the JavaScript properties as methods...

```
// ORIGINAL/INCORRECT CODE
// x.style.fontSize('20px');
// x.style.fontFamily('arial');
// x.style.color('#008080');
// x.style.border('10px solid #000');
```

Corrected...

```
// CORRECTED
// These are properties, NOT methods.
x.style.fontSize = '20px';
x.style.fontFamily = 'arial';
x.style.color = '#008080';
x.style.border = '10px solid #000';
```

Answer (score 1):

Judging from the picture of your code that you posted (http://jsfiddle.net is a better option for this sort of thing), your JavaScript is wrong.

```
x.style.fontSize('20px');
```

The `style` object on HTML elements does not have a *function* called `fontSize`, it has a `property` called `fontSize`. You assign your desired value to it, like this:

```
x.style.fontSize = '20px';
```

If you try your original code in e.g. Chrome with the JavaScript console visible (View > Developer > JavaScript Console), you should see an error when you try to run your original code.

Comment: Here's a working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RkHpg/), illustrating how it should look like.

Answer (score 0):

Those style attributes are properties not methods. That is to say, it should not be `x.style.fontSize('20px')`, but rather `x.style.fontSize = '20px'`.

Answer (score -1):

You have incorrectly referred to the style. You have to refer to it as `x.style.fontSize = '20px'`. Instead of which you have recently chosen `x.style.fontSize('20px')`. Hope this helps!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34123468)